# How to make the array packets private and accessing them in C

Tags: c, arrays, return, structure

I wanted to know how could i make my code better by declaring the array 'data_pack[]' as a private .Im working in embedded field so i have limited RAM and  Memory and all i wanted to do is  two things.

> 1.I have a serial UI which gives me serial data of 50 Bytes and stores them directly to unsigned char data_pack[50]
>
> 2.And I wanted to access the array in another module to calculate and do other things.

Currently im keeping the array as global variable and can be accessed from any module in my project.If i wanted to keep  data_pack[50] as private how can i access the array packets in another modules?

```
I hope i will be more clearer after explaining here:
 I have four modules. 
 main.c
 ui.c 
 display.c
 display2.c
```

And If i wanted to keep data_pack[50] as pvt in ui.c and access it in other modules..how can i do it with out making it global.

> For eg: In ui.c I would like the data_pack[] to get filled in and in
>   display.c and display2.c I want to access the array and read its
>   element.In that case how could i pass the array in to other source
>   files

What would be the best way to access data_pack[] by keeping it as private?
Or should i use structures instead?

Comment: No need to make it global.  Pass it as a parameter, or restrict it to a single translation unit by giving it internal linkage.

Comment: Passing it as parameter by that u meant about about pointer to the first array location?

Comment: If you are accessing `data_pack` in other compilation units, why do you want to make it private? Do you want other modules to be able to read the data, but not write to it?

Comment: Yes exactly I wanted to use and store data_pack[] in one source file and read the same array in multiple source files.

Comment: In that case, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a global variable `data_pack` read-only in other compilation units by changing its forward reference to `extern const ...`. For example, two files:

**file1.c**

```
char example[50] = {1, 2, 3};

void change() {
    example[1] = 44;
}
```

**file2.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* extern const char example[50]; array size not needed in extern declaration */
extern const char example[];
void change();

int main() {
    printf("%d\n", example[1]); /* works */
    change();
    printf("%d\n", example[1]);
    /* example[0] = 45; would cause a compile error */
    return 0;
}
```

Therefore, **file2.c** will see example as an array of constant ints, meaning it can only be modified by **file1.c**. The code above would print 2, followed by 44.

<s>However, you must be careful doing this. If the size of the array in the forward declaration differs from the actual size of the array in the compilation unit it is contained in, the compiler/linker *will not* tell you (at least it doesn't for me, using `gcc -Wall -Wextra -ansi -pedantic`).</s> You can also leave the array size out of the extern declaration.

One thing to note is that the compiler may attempt to optimize the `const` value, as it may not expect the value to change, thus producing invalid optimizations. I've performed some tests, and GCC doesn't seem to do this, but as it is undefined behaviour you may wish to use a getter/setter solution instead.

Comment: Thank you Quackmatic, Mine wont be constants actually..It will be a stream of data stored in array data_pack[].And if i wanted to access them in other filesas you pointed out how can do effectively.

Comment: The data in `example` is only a constant where it is declared as such. The data in `example` can still be modified in **file1.c**, as shown in my edit. Therefore, **file1.c** can read *and* write the data in `example`, but **file2.c** can only read it.

Comment: In the case of an external declaration, it's possible to not specify the size of the array. This is useful to avoid mistakes.

Comment: That's true. I added the array size more for clarity than anything, but you are correct - you can leave it out. You get no bounds checking either way so I suppose it makes little to no difference.

Comment: I would be very cautious about using non-matching type qualifiers on `extern` declarations. Standard specifically forbids treating `const char` as `char`, but is more ambiguous about treating `char` as `const char`: *"For two qualified types to be compatible, both shall have the identically qualified version
of a compatible type"*. While this might not be an issue on any modern system, it still might be safer to use getter function instead of extern declaration: `const char * getExampleArray(void)`

Comment: If you do this, give example internal linkage in file1.c by declaring it `static char example[50]`

Comment: And don't provide an external definition, but add a getter in file1.c